# Django forms + jQuery

Tags: python, jquery, django

How to use jQuery mask plugin (javascript in general) in template to validate and style a field and update the data in the DB ?

In the example below I use : https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ to validate a PhoneNumberField and Widget Tweaks to style the field.

**models.py**

```
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    user_photo = forms.ImageField(label='Profile photo', required=False, error_messages={'invalid': 'Image files only'}, widget=forms.FileInput)

    company_logo = forms.ImageField(label='Company logo', required=False, error_messages={'invalid': 'Image files only'}, widget=forms.FileInput)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('company_name', 'company_logo', 'user_photo', 'desc', 'dep', **'phone_number'**)
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def dashboard_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user,
                                 data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile,
                                       data=request.POST,
                                       files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            print(profile_form)
            messages.success(request, 'Profile updated successfully')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error updating your profile')
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request,
                  'back/index.html',
                  {'user_form': user_form,
                   'profile_form': profile_form})
```

**index.html**

```
<input type="text" class="js-masked-input form-control" name="phone" id="phoneLabel" placeholder="+x(xxx)xxx-xx-xx" aria-label="+x(xxx)xxx-xx-xx" value="+1(605)5618929"
                             data-hs-mask-options='{
                               "template": "+0(000)000-00-00"
                             }'>
```

Comment: Have you added jQuery mask plugin's js into your HTML template?

Comment: <input type="text" class="js-masked-input form-control" name="phone" id="phoneLabel" placeholder="+x(xxx)xxx-xx-xx" aria-label="+x(xxx)xxx-xx-xx" value="+1(605)5618929"
                             data-hs-mask-options='{
                               "template": "+0(000)000-00-00"
                             }'>

Comment: no I mean have you downloaded from https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/ and added to your HTML file

Comment: configure js file which is provided in src

Comment: The jQuery Mask Plugin is in my staticfiles folder. The template works fine but my question is how can I use widget tweaks to update date still keeping styling provided by jQuery plugin. 
Somithing like :

{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% render_field profile_form.phone_number class+="js-masked-input form-control" value="" ...... %}